# How to make this "bumpy sphere" shape in C4D?

Tags: 3d, cinema4d

I'm new to Cinema 4D, but I can't figure out how to make this kind of shape. (Currently I have a spikey ball I made by selecting points and jutting them out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: Example of shape]) 
[image: What I'm trying to make]
[image: What I currently have]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Started with the soccerball mesh preset, selected the polys only in the black portions, scaled them (non-uniformly on purpose) and then made that a sub-D surface.

Might be a good starting direction...

[image]